# Create multiple objects on a button click in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have *template_sections* and *sections* and on a button click in my view I want

a) get all *template_sections* with a specific template_id, send them to the sections_controller

or

b) the section_controller method *transform* should get the template_sections there

and

iterate over them and create a new section object for each one of them, where I would set *is_template = 0* and *template_id = nil* and save them.

**View:**

```
<div class="col-2 deploy-template">
  <%= button_to 'Deploy Template', transform_sections_path, method: :post, *{call controller's method or send objects from here to transform method}*, remote: true, type: 'button', class: "btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-0 mr-4" %>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
def new
  @section = Section.new
  if params[:is_template]
    date = (Time.at(params['day'].to_i*86400-1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    @section.starts_at_datetime = (date + ' ' + params['time']).in_time_zone rescue nil
  else
    @section.starts_at_datetime = (params['date'] + ' ' + params['time']).in_time_zone rescue nil
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

def create
  @section = Section.new(section_params)
  @section.account_id = session_account_id
  @section.is_template = true if params[:section][:is_template] == 'true'
  @section.template_id = params[:section][:template_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @section.save
      format.js
      flash.now[:success] = "saved successfuly"
      create_event @section, "create", "Create"
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "#{@section.errors.full_messages}"
      format.js { render 'layouts/notifications' }
    end
  end
end

def transform
  template_sections.each do |template_section|
  #save each template_section with is_template = 0 and template_id = nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pass your template sections to your controller through the params hash like so:

```
<%= button_to 'Deploy Template', method: :post, transform_sections_path(template_sections: [YOUR ARRAY VARIABLE HERE]), remote: true, type: 'button', class: "btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-0 mr-4" %>
```

Your template sections should then be available through params[:template_sections] inside of your controller for you to do whatever you feel like doing, (I am assuming post: template_sections_path points to the transform action in your controller).

```
def transform
  template_sections = params[:template_sections]
  template_sections.each do |template_section|
  #save each template_section with is_template = 0 and template_id = nil
end
```

I don't know what your TemplateSection model looks like so I will refrain from writing controller code that won't work, but hopefully once you have the data in your controller you will be able to work through it, and if not I am happy to help with a little bit more information.

As an additional note, "method: :post", and "type: button" seem redundant when using a button_to tag as those are the defaults, you can remove them unless you have a specific reason for having them.